# Adding a prebuilt binary in Android source

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I have a native binary that I want to include into Android's source code, so that when I compile it my binary will be included in /system/bin .

I've copied my binary into the folder /prebuilt/android-arm/my-binary , and I've created a new Android.mk with the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my-binary
LOCAL_MODULE := my-binary
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

But when I run *make*, the only reference I get in the log is the following:

```
target Prebuilt: my-binary (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/my-binary_intermediates/my-binary)
```

And the binary isn't installed into system.img at all. There's an almost identical question in [Installing a prebuilt binary on Android: "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043257/installing-a-prebuilt-binary-on-android-not-found) , but the asker already knew the basic procedure and it isn't explained at all. If I run *make my-binary*, I get the same line I posted.

I've also tried to run *make out/target/product/generic/system.img my-binary* but it doesn't work either. My binary shows up in the the *out* subfolder but it won't be included into system.imng

Am I missing something? Is there any way so that with just running *make -j#* my binary will be included in /system/bin ?

Answer (score 9):

Just tested on my emulator and it's working. I used as an example gdbserver in this folder. I have a strace crosscompiled for android and use it to be embedded into the image. So, the instructions will be for this executable.

1. Create a folder under prebuilt/android-arm/strace
2. Put there your binary (in my case strace)

Add Android.mk file with the following content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := strace
LOCAL_MODULE := strace
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)


prebuilt_files :=

$(call add-prebuilt-files, EXECUTABLES, $(prebuilt_files))
```

Build with the instruction: `mmm prebuilt snod -j4` (if you have images already built) or you, of course, can use `make -j4` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I used the Android.mk found in the gdbserver in the same directory for reference, but it wasn't working for some readon. I'm gonna try with mmmm; I'll be right back...

EDIT: *mmm prebuilt snod -j* worked! I'm going to do a *make clean* and see if rebuilding everything from scratch works as well...

Comment: Something really weird is going on... Running *make* on the source code straight from repo (without my binary) compiles fine. But when I add my binary, I get weird errors. The worst thing is that even if I do a *make clean* and take out my folder (which should let the source code just as it was at the beginning since I'm not touching anything else), when I try to compile it I'll still get compiling errors. I'm freeing space nad making sure it's not anything not related to the code itself (I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on VMware)

Comment: make clean simply delete 'out' folder. It does not change code to defaoult. Can you update your answer with the errors that you get during the compilation?

Comment: Nevermind... I re-downloaded the source from repo and built it without ccache and using plain *make*, wihtout any -j4, and it just built. Anyway, it's still not working; my binary doesn't appear in /system/bin when using DDMS on the emulator.

Comment: It's strange. I see this file in my emulator - I've just checked.

Answer (score 4):

if your binary ends up in the out directory but not in the image, it's because you don't have a rule to include the binary in the image.

in `device/<vendorname>/<devicename>/device.mk` (or in some makefile included by `device.mk`) you need to have one of two entries:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += my-binary
```

or:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += path/to/my-binary:/root/target/path/to/my-binary
```

... I would suggest the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` approach; `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` is better suited to scripts and configuration files.

NOTE: `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` uses the module name, where `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` uses the actual name/location of the binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also the following which works for me
.....
LOCAL_MDULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)
...
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)